# Angular 2 app is very slow on android devices

Tags: android, angular, optimization, angular-ui-router

I have built an angular 2 app using the angular seed project. But the application is very slow on android devices. I am using lazy loading. For testing purpose I disabled all the pages and kept only the 404 page . But just the 404 page is also take 9 sec to see the page. Please can anyone help me optimize the loading time. I am attaching the screen shot below of the production build. 
In the network there are lot of breaks. I don't know why that is happening

[image]

Comment: There will need to be some code or something to work off of.  Also, is there a local databqse or all online?

Comment: Thanks for relying Sol .The project is not live and the project code is not open to any one since it a private project for a company .But I can provide screen shots of the network tab or any particular files if required.

Comment: Are you using AOT? It looks like it takes a long time to bootstrap

Comment: IT is ok to reveal code if you change the names to obscure it somewhat.   The biggest problems I have seen usually deal with not making things asyncronous

Comment: No I am just using Lazy loading . AOT is making a build problem when i use  it along with Lazy loading in the angular seed project.

Comment: @Sol .  This is a repository to my project . It  contains just the modules ,routing and config files .. https://github.com/clevegomes/angular2Sample   app.module.ts is the entry module and toplevel.routes.ts is the entry routes

Answer (score 0):

I was analysis my angular project and I noticed that using require() makes the app slow on android devices .
In order to make my app size small i have used used systemjs to load libraries later (example datepicker ,moment etc) in my components

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');

declare var moment:any;
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "timezone",
    templateUrl: "timeZone.component.html"
})

export class TimeZoneComponent implements OnInit {
```

But Loading the module containing this component is taking time .

Secondly lazy loading a module is also taking time to load the app. After the spinner stops loading there is a delay till the module is lazy loading.

```
 { path: 'home', loadChildren: './app/core/publicPage/publicPage.module#PublicPageModule' },
```

Making the above changes the app loads on android devices in 13 sec other than previous 22 sec .(Which is still not good enough but much better)

I don't know if this is an issue with systemjs on android devices. Has any one faced this simlar issue with system js ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally  removed system  js and implemented webpack with aot. now my application  is very fast on android.  I guess  system js is not production ready.